# 400 bad request invalid header error when setting up IIs bindings

Tags: iis

I've set up an A record with an IP address that points to my server. From my server, I have set up an IIS website pointing to a local folder with a published ASP.net project. My IIS bindings for both the naked and www. domains are both pointed to the same IP as my A records.

My problem comes from if I attempt to access my domain, where I'm met with a 400 bad request error (header invalid).

Could someone please help me on this.

I've attempted to stop my IIS site, this has absolutely no affect on the error which leads me to believe that it's not making any attempt to bind to my IIS site.

Comment: Can you run a report to confirm what you described? https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html

Comment: You can try to increase extend request length to solve this issue `<system.web><httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2097151" executionTimeout="2097151" />
</system.web>`, if that doesn't work, you can use failed request tracking to view detailed error information.